# Cambiar valores de un array mediante eventos

Tags: javascript, array, lógica

Estoy intentando hacer un `array` que obtenga los valores de una serie de 3 `inputs` dentro de `divs` generados dinámicamente.

Cada `input` tiene su evento `change` con el cual se cambia el valor correspondiente del objeto[0] del `array`. Una vez generamos otro `div`, esta lógica hace aguas por todas partes, ya que, por ejemplo, el segundo input del segundo div, cambiaría el segundo valor del PRIMER objeto del array. Objeto[0].

```js
let array = [];
let info = [];

if (array.length == 0) {
  createElements();
  doTxt();
}

function createElements() {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let Finp = document.createElement('input');
  let Sinp = document.createElement('input');
  let Tinp = document.createElement('input');

  div.setAttribute('class', 'content');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  div.style.width = '500px';
  div.style.height = '50px';
  Finp.setAttribute('class', 'F-uno');
  Sinp.setAttribute('class', 'S-dos');
  Tinp.setAttribute('class', 'T-tres');

  info.push({
    value_1: Finp.value,
    value_2: Sinp.value,
    value_3: Tinp.value
  });

  doTxt(info);


  Finp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let chk = checkVacuum();

    if (Finp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    } else if (Finp.value != '' && chk != true) {
      createElements();
    }

    info[0].value_1 = Finp.value; //Este 0 deberia cambiar
    doTxt(info);
  });

  Sinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    }

    info[0].value_2 = Sinp.value; //Este 0 deberia cambiar
    doTxt(info);
  });

  Tinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Tinp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    }

    info[0].value_3 = Tinp.value; //Este 0 deberia cambiar
    doTxt(info);
  });

  div.append(Finp, Sinp, Tinp);
  document.body.append(div);
  //setChanges();
}

function checkVacuum() {
  let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  let n = elm.length - 1;

  if (elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[1].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[2].value == '' && elm[n] != elm[0]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function doTxt(info) {
  if (!document.getElementById('txt-info')) {
    let txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt-info');
    txt.style.position = 'absolute';
    txt.style.top = '0';
    txt.style.right = '0';
    txt.innerHTML = [];
    document.body.append(txt);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('txt-info').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info);
  }
}
```

Como podréis ver, si escribimos cualquier cosa en los `input` del primer `div`, se genera tal y como yo quiero el `array` de la derecha. El problema viene en que si os fijáis, todos los eventos de dichos `input` van ligados al objeto [0] del `array`, por tanto, si el segundo `div` tiene que cambiar los valores del objeto[1] del `array`, se me cae la lógica.

Ahí está el fallo y lo que no se solucionar. Dicho [0] debería cambiar según qué `div` tuviera que mirar.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo correctamente?

---

**[EDIT]**

He probado esta solución, y realmente funciona, PERO, tiene como inconveniente que se generan demasiados eventos. Trato de quitarlos pero no hay tu tía:

```
function setChanges(){
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach((item, index)=>{
        //item.querySelectorAll('input')[0].removeEventListener('keydown', null);

        item.querySelectorAll('input')[0].addEventListener('keydown', ()=>{
            info[index].value_1 = item.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value;
            doTxt(info);
        });

        // item.querySelectorAll('input')[1].removeEventListener('keydown');
        // item.querySelectorAll('input')[2].removeEventListener('keydown');
        
    });

}
```

Cada vez que se añade un `div` nuevo, pasa esa función al final. El problema es que genera demasiados eventos, ya que el removeEventListener() no funciona.
Asumo que porque al principio no hay ninguno, y luego hay dos directamente cuando quiere volver a comprobarlo.

Comment: He hecho [una pequeña demo](https://codepen.io/VRoxa/pen/vYmxZbW), que no sé si es exactamente lo que buscas. Just chillin'. Creo que quizás pueda darte alguna idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una posible alternativa que hace  el manejo del `array`, las funciones de validación  y eliminación de fila las completas porque no son complejas.

Sobre  tu código he realizado algunas  variantes:

1. Separar la creación del  `div` de los `input`.
2. A cada `input`  le voy agregar un `id` cuyo  valor es el último indice que se abre. Por ejemplo: la fila 1 tendrá  F0,S0,T0, la fila 2 F1,S2,T2, y así sucesivamente. Esto me va  a servir para tener en  el input el  `indice` que le corresponde en el arreglo.
3. Agrego un sólo `listener` al evento `change` del `div`, de este modo tendré un solo controlador de eventos en lugar de tener uno por input.
4. En el controlador de evento,  el `event.target` me indica el elemento donde se produjo el evento y con ello, saco el  `indice`  de `id` y las demás asignaciones.

Ya le agregas  las funcionalidad de validación. Asimismo, se puede mejorar. Toma nota que la función  `checkVaccum` debería recibir como parametro event.target. La verdad no he tocado  esa función.

```
    let array = [];
    let info = [];

    if (array.length == 0) {
      createElements();
      doTxt();
    }



/*  Crea los INPUTS */

    function  createInputs() {
      let Finp = document.createElement('input');
      let Sinp = document.createElement('input');
      let Tinp = document.createElement('input');
      Finp.setAttribute('class', 'F-uno');
      Sinp.setAttribute('class', 'S-dos');
      Tinp.setAttribute('class', 'T-tres');
      document.querySelector("div.content").append(Finp, Sinp, Tinp);
      info.push({
        value_1: Finp.value,
        value_2: Sinp.value,
        value_3: Tinp.value
      });    
      Finp.setAttribute('id', 'F'+(info.length-1));
      Sinp.setAttribute('id', 'S'+(info.length-1));
      Tinp.setAttribute('id', 'T'+(info.length-1));
      doTxt(info);
    }


    function createElements() {

      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('class', 'content');
      div.style.width = '700px';
      div.style.height = '70px';
      document.body.append(div);
      createInputs();
    }
    
   // Agrega el listener para los inputs changes 
    document.querySelector("div.content").addEventListener("change",function(e) {

        if (e.target && e.target.matches("input")) {
          let n=e.target.id.substr(1);

          if(e.target.matches("input.F-uno")){
            info[n].value_1 =e.target.value; 
            createInputs();
          }
          else if(e.target.matches("input.S-dos"))
            info[n].value_2 = e.target.value;
          else if(e.target.matches("input.T-tres")){
            info[n].value_3 = e.target.value;
            doTxt(info);
         }
        }
      });

    function checkVacuum() {
      let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
      let n = elm.length - 1;
      if (elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[1].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[2].value == '' && elm[n] != elm[0]) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function doTxt(info) {
      if (!document.getElementById('txt-info')) {
        let txt = document.createElement('textarea');
        txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt-info');
        txt.style.position = 'absolute';
        txt.style.top = '0';
        txt.style.right = '0';
        txt.innerHTML = [];
        document.body.append(txt);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('txt-info').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo por mi cuenta, igualmente veré como funciona lo tuyo porque parece más limpio

Comment: Acabo de comprobarlo, y cuando borras todos los valores de los input de un mismo div, no borra la información del objeto, del array ni el propio div de inputs. Pero contando con que eso no lko había preguntado te lo doy por válido, que me acabo de dar cuenta qiue eso no estaba en mi rpegunta XD

Answer (score 1):

Esto sería concretamente lo que estaba buscando:

```js
let array = [];
let info = [];

if (array.length == 0) {
  createElements();
  doTxt();
}

function createElements() {

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let Finp = document.createElement('input');
  let Sinp = document.createElement('input');
  let Tinp = document.createElement('input');
  let obj = {};

  div.setAttribute('class', 'content');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  div.style.width = '500px';
  div.style.height = '50px';
  Finp.setAttribute('class', 'F-uno');
  Sinp.setAttribute('class', 'S-dos');
  Tinp.setAttribute('class', 'T-tres');

  Finp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let chk = checkVacuum();

    if (Finp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      doTxt(obj, Finp, 1);
    } else if (Finp.value != '' && chk != true) {
      createElements();
    }

    obj.value_1 = Finp.value;
    doTxt(obj, Finp);
  });

  Sinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      doTxt(obj, Sinp, 1);
    } else {
      obj.value_2 = Sinp.value;
      doTxt(obj, Sinp);
    }
  });

  Tinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Tinp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      doTxt(obj, Tinp, 1);
    } else {
      obj.value_3 = Tinp.value;
      doTxt(obj, Tinp);
    }
  });

  div.append(Finp, Sinp, Tinp);
  document.body.append(div);
}

function checkVacuum() {
  let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  let n = elm.length - 1;

  if (elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[1].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[2].value == '' && elm[n] != elm[0]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function doTxt(obj, elm, del) {

  if (!document.getElementById('txt-info')) {
    let txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt-info');
    txt.style.position = 'absolute';
    txt.style.top = '0';
    txt.style.right = '0';
    txt.innerHTML = [];
    document.body.append(txt);
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach((item, index) => {

      if (item == elm.parentNode) {
        if (del) {
          info.splice(index, 1);
          elm.parentNode.remove();
        } else {
          info[index] = obj;
          console.log(info);
          document.getElementById('txt-info').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```